# Dimension of the set W

Tags: linear-algebra

Say there is a set $W$ such that $W = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_n\} \mid x_1 + \ldots + x_n = 0\}, $ where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$. Can we conclude that the dimension of $W$ is $n-1$? If yes, why?

I need this result for a proof I am working on. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the dimension of $W$ is $n-1$.

Define the map $l:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $l(   (x_1, x_2, \dots,x_n)) = x_1 +x_2 +\cdots x_n$.

This map is obviously non trivial, and it is sujective therefore the dimension of its image is $1$. Alos notice that $W= \rm{ker}(l)$

Now rank nullity theorem suggests $\rm{dim}(W)=\dim \mathbb{R}^n-1=n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

yes, since we know that $x_n=-x_1-...-x_{n-1}$. That is we know that $W$ has $(n-1)$ linearly independent generators, so the cardinality of basis is $(n-1)$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. More generally, the number of *linearly independent* equations that define $W$ is equal to the *codimension* of $W$, i. e. the difference between the dimension of the ambient space and $\dim W$.